# Highlighted Check box inside a webgrid is not getting selected in IE7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

My application is in MVC 3 and I am using razor engine, I am trying to select first item (default highlighted check box) inside a web grid, it is not getting selected in IE7, here is the code:

```
$("#@item").change(function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... Lets take it step by step ... cause you didnt offer much data ... Im going to make a scenario for you :

lets say you have this checkbox :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.isValid,new {id="chkValid"})
```

Of course ISValid is a bool variable.

One easy way would be doing so :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.isValid,new {@checked = "checked"})
```

Now if for some reason that doesnt work ... you can always go the old fashioned way ... Jquery : 
in document ready .. do this :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('chkValid').attr('checked')= true;
    });
```

Hope it helps

---

LATER EDIT: 
Ok ... Try this :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.isValid,new {id="chkValid" , onclick="updateChk("+@model.parameter+")"}) // the value you need to send to the controller
```

and this is the jquery function :

```
  function updateChk(parameter)
    {
            if (($('#chkValid').is(':checked')) {
                var check = true;
            } else {
                check = false;
            }
    //see if checkbox is checked and pass it to the controller in an Ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',

                data: "{parameter:parameter, status:'" + check + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                }
            });
        }
```

If you dont understand something let me know !

Comment: Thanks Mihai Labo for your replay,but i want to get the click event of the checkbox,the check box is inside my webgrid and it is like  grid.Column(format: 
            @<text><input class="box"  type="checkbox" @(item.isSelected ? "Checked" : null) id="@item.chkValid" value="@item.ID"/>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 $("#@item.chkValid").change(function () {
//doing something...
}
here @item.isSelected is boolean

Comment: let me get this straight ... you want it to do a certain action once the checkbox is selected/deselected

Comment: yes..but it is not happening for the first checkbox since it is hightlighted...this issue only happens in IE7